# Document version column in spreadsheet view

Tags: sharepoint, moss

I try to open MOSS document library in spreadsheet view and when I add version of document, I see it in regular view and don't see in spreadsheet view.

When I try to export to Excel I get the same problem.

Comment: Regular view with the Version column saved? Does the list have versioning enabled?

Answer (score 0):

May be that the library supports versioning - in that case the document might not be displayed as it is still draft. What happens if you remove versioning?